# Teradata TPT_INFRA: TPT02640: Error: Conflicting column count

Tags: teradata

I am facing issues in Teradata parallel transporter while loading data from TEST to DEV environment. The table structure are the same, however I face the error

> TPT_INFRA: TPT02640: Error: Conflicting column count. Source column
>   count (20) Target column count (13). EXPORT_OPERATOR: TPT12108: Output
>   Schema does not match data from SELECT statement

Comment: Obviously the table structures are **not** the same or you use a specific schema.

Comment: Got the below resolution from Teradata forum and it works : By default, TPT is supporting a DECIMAL precision of 18 (8 bytes).
Since your source column is defined as DECIMAL with a precision of 22 (needing 16 bytes), you need to add the MaxDecimalDigits=31 to the Export operator definition.
The Export operator will then tell the database that it can support Large Decimal columns and the full 16 bytes will be exported, not just 8.

Answer (score 0):

check the schema file you have generated. Seems to be an issue with your source file and the schema file generated.